Understand the constant related to the continuity of the extension operator in Sobolev Spaces
We know that the extension theorem steams that for a given $\Omega$ bounded domain, $\Omega \subset \subset V$ and $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ there exists $E(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that:

$E(u) = u$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$;
$\text{supp}(E(u)) \subset V$,
There exists $C > 0$ such that  $\|E(u)\|_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C \|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}$, where $C$ depends on $\Omega$ and $V$.

I want to apply this result in the following way: Let $\Omega := B_\delta(0)$ where $\delta >0$ and $V_\epsilon := B_{\delta + \epsilon}(0)$ where $0 < \epsilon < 1$. So there exists $E_\epsilon(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that:

$E_\epsilon(u) = u$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$;
$\text{supp}(E_\epsilon(u)) \subset V_\epsilon$,
There exists $C_\epsilon > 0$ such that  $\|E(u)\|_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C_\epsilon \|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}$.

Notice that $V_\epsilon \subset B_{\delta + 1}(0)$ for all $0 <\epsilon < 1$. I wonder if the constants $C_\epsilon$ are bounded from above by a uniforme constant depending on $B_{\delta + 1}$. Or, if from the proof of the result, is it possible to take $C_\epsilon$ not depending on $\epsilon$. Any help or idea to prove or desaprove it is welcome.
